# Will my database connections have problems?

Tags: python, sql, django, celery

In my django project, I am using celery to run a periodic task that will check a URL that responds with a json and updating my database with some elements from that json.

Since requesting from the URL is limited, the total process of updating the whole database with my task will take about 40 minutes and I will run the task every 2 hours.

If I check a view of my django project, which also requests information from the database while the task is asynchronously running in the background, will I run into any problems?

Answer (score 0):

While requesting information from your database you are reading your database. And in your celery task your are writing data into your database. You can write only once at a time but read as many times as you want as there is no lock permission on database while reading.

Answer (score 0):

The only time when you are going to run into issues while using db with celery is when you use the database as backend for celery because it will continuously poll the db for tasks. If you use a normal broker you should not have issues.